# Show each row number in table RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RoR. I am making an article table which contains article title and article text. I am showing it in a table. So far so good. What I want to do next is to show ROW NUMBER in my table.
Here is my code:

```
  <table>
  <tr>
here-> <th> RowNum </th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th> 
</tr>

<% @articles.each do |article| %>
<tr>
    <td> <%= article.title %></td>
    <td> <%= article.text %></td>   
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I've tried with $. magich variable and $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `@articles.each_with_index do |article, index|`

Then add `<%= index %>` in your table.

Comment: how to out the index value?

Comment: thanks very much. is there a way that I can start count from 1? because it shows me 0 at the first row?

Comment: Sure. Change <%= index %> to <%= index + 1 %>

Comment: @BorisPetrov you can also use `@articles.each.with_index(1)` to get a 1-based index.